# How to write a shell (.sh) script for the following

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm new to linux/unix shell scripting, and I have a few dozen projects that I want to set up Subversion folders for (eventually I'll get to Git lol).  How do I write a script to do the following:

1. Get a list of all sub-folders in a folder
2. For each sub-folder, use it execute the following commands:

> ```
> svnadmin create /var/www/svn/<sub-folder>
>
> svn import /var/www/<sub-folder> file:///var/www/svn/<sub-folder>
>
> chmod -R 777 var/www/svn/<sub-folder>
>
> chown -R apache.apache var/www/svn/<sub-folder>
> ```

From what I've seen on the internet so far, I suppose I put it all into a .sh file and type something like :

```
.sh thing.sh
```

... to execute it.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in `find -maxdepth 1 -type d`; do
  svnadmin create "/var/www/svn/$i"
  svn import "/var/www/$i" "file:///var/www/svn/$i"
  chmod -R 777 "var/www/svn/$i"
  chown -R apache.apache "var/www/svn/$i"
done
```

Of course your `svn import` command is incorrect, and pathes in your `chmod` and `chown` missing `/`. But it's copypaste of your commands, anyway.

Comment: If it needs to be applied for all sub-directories ( as per problem statement ), then I think we need not have to put '-maxdepth 1' condition to find

Comment: Thanks keltar, for the script and the path and syntax corrections.  You are also correct with the single depth sub-directories (my bad for not specifying earlier, sorry everyone).

Comment: please edit chmod and chown.. you're missing a / at the beginning of the path

Comment: It is intentionally copied from question, and i explicitly stated that it is very likely to be incorrect. Question is about iteration through directories, so is the answer - from my side i can't tell, maybe it was the whole idea to run exactly that commands.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in `ls`
do
    if test -d $FILE
    then      
        svnadmin create /var/www/svn/$FILE
        svn import /var/www/$FILE file:///var/www/svn/$FILE
        chmod -R 777 /var/www/svn/$FILE
        chown -R apache.apache /var/www/svn/$FILE
    fi
done
```

After saving execute `chmod +x {name of file}` on the script to make it executable with `./{name of file}` or `sh {name of file}`.

In case you need all subfolders recursively from current folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in `find . -type d`
do
    if test -d $FILE
    then      
        svnadmin create /var/www/svn/$FILE
        svn import /var/www/$FILE file:///var/www/svn/$FILE
        chmod -R 777 /var/www/svn/$FILE
        chown -R apache.apache /var/www/svn/$FILE
    fi
done
```

If you have any questions please comment.

Comment: I think It will not look for sub directories under the directory from which you are running from

Comment: No, it will only take the folders in a current folder. If you need it recursively you will have to use `find`. You haven't mentioned recursion. I will edit it in.

Comment: `-l` flag have to be removed, or you'll iterate through a lot of garbage, not just file names.

Comment: And in case of `svn` recursive iteration is meaningless - because it imports starting from specified path recursively. Comment is actually misleading, and it isn't made by OP.

Comment: @Dropout er... i meant, why not just `ls` without parameters?

Comment: @keltar lol you're right, sorry I'm doing 10 things at the same time and sometimes I forget to think and I overcomplicate things :) edited

Answer (score 1):

You could create a script doIt.sh with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
svnadmin create /var/www/svn/$1
svn import /var/www/$1 file:///var/www/svn/$1
chmod -R 777 var/www/svn/$1
chown -R apache.apache var/www/svn/$1
```

Then you can go into the folder in which you want to find all subfolders and execute the following:

```
find . -type d | xargs -I {} ./doIt.sh {}
```

---

Also, are you sure of this line:

```
svn import /var/www/<sub-folder> file:///var/www/svn/<sub-folder>
```

Did you not mean:

```
svn import /var/www/svn/<sub-folder> file:///var/www/svn/<sub-folder>
```

**Note: Missing svn subfolder in path**